# passing data between views on the iPhone using singletons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view, singleton

I am trying to use the code found here [enter link description here](http://iphone.galloway.me.uk/iphone-sdktutorials/singleton-classes/) to pass data between two views.

It is not working.

The only value that is available globally to me is the `someProperty` value that was set when the object was instantiated.

If I update `someProperty` and try and access it from another view it just spits out the value it was created with.

Basically I am unable to update the variables of the singleton.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Hey guys I found the solution: Basically I have a button that 1) reads login details from UITextFields and 2) flips the view and then displays the login details.

The problem was I was flipping the view before reading the variables, not giving the app enough time to read the variables. Making the function read the variables first and then flip the view solved it!

Thanks anyway guys :D

I am using it as instructed: I put `MyManager *sharedManager = [MyManager sharedManager];`

in each .m file that I want to access the data from.

Thanks very much for your time

Comment: post the code where you are updating the singleton's properties

Comment: I found the solution: Basically I have a button that 1) reads login details from UITextFields and 2) flips the view and then displays the login details.

The problem was I was flipping the view before reading the variables, not giving the app enough time to read the variables. Making the function read the variables first and then flip the view solved it!

Thanks anyway guys :D

I am using it as instructed: I put MyManager *sharedManager = [MyManager sharedManager];

in each .m file that I want to access the data from.

Thanks very much for your time